# How do I use my app delegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, background, appdelegate

I have a method called "pauseGame:" that pauses the game and a method called "resumeGame:"
I was wondering how I would call these in my app delegate I tried a few ways but in my debugger it ended up saying "pauseGame: method not found" and i imported my class i declared them in into my app delegate I was trying to figure out how I could solve this.

Here is the code I used for it:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    [BPGameController pauseGame:]; 
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    [BPGameController pauseGame:]; 
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    [BPGameController resumeGame:]; 
}
```

Comment: Can u put ur code? So, I can trace down the code

Comment: - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [BPGameController pauseGame:];

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [BPGameController pauseGame:];
}

Comment: - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [BPGameController resumeGame:];
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this. and make sure the method resumeGame is working fine.

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application { 

    [super applicationDidBecomeActive:application];

    [BPGameController resumeGame:]; 

    }
```

Comment: it says "no visible @interface for 'UIResponder' declares the selector 'applicationDidBecomeActive:'

Comment: and for the second line it still says "expected expression"

Comment: can I see your pauseGame and resumeGame methods?

Comment: - (IBAction)pauseGame:(id)sender {
    
    [greenTimer invalidate];
}                                                                   - (IBAction)resumeGame:(id)sender {
    
    greenTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(greenBlocksMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

Answer (score 0):

Are your pause/resume methods class methods or instance methods, in your code example it looks like you're calling them as class methods. Can you post more concrete code?

Signatures would help.

If those methods are instance methods, what you can do is add a property to `YourAppDelegate`, where it might look like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) BPGameController *bpgc;
```

And then when you instantiate the `BPGameController` somewhere else, set it on the appdelegate by doing

```
[(*YourAppDelegate)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setBpgc:yourBPGC];
```

and then in the app delegate methods, you can reference your bpgc by `self.bpgc` and send messages like `pauseGame`, etc.

Comment: my pause/resume methods are instance methods of my BPGameController class, and im trying to use them in my appDelegate

Comment: how would i call them as instance methods?

Comment: BPGameController *svc = [[BPGameController alloc] init];
    [svc pauseGame:(id)];  i tried using this to call the instance method but it still says "expected expression"

Comment: Either: 1. Change them to class methods if they don't depend on any instance data. 2. Somehow pass the instance of BPGameController to your `AppDelegate` and then call the instance method on that. It doesn't work if you alloc init another one because that operates on a new instance of the BPGameController, which is not what you want.

Comment: do you know how i could pass the instance of BPGameController to my app delegate, the only way I could think of was the alloc init, but you said its not what I want

Comment: would I put that code "[(*yourAppDelegate)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setBpgc:yourBPGC]; inside my applicationwillResign method i Just tried doing it but I dont think I did it the right way

Comment: No, you put it wherever you created your BPGameController.

Comment: And `yourBPGC` should be the game controller you just created.

Answer (score 0):

First your code is syntatically incorrect.AS

```
 [BPGameController pauseGame:]; //do not call pauseGame: wihout any parameter.
```

instead consider calling it with `nil` if you do not have any value

```
   [BPGameController pauseGame:nil];
```

or
   If you function do not need parameters than remove from method definition.

Secondly I suspect you do not have `pauseGame:` declared in `.h` file

declare it in `.h` file.If not

Third if you want to call `pauseGame` this way`[BPGameController pauseGame:nil];` than your method definition should start with `+` instead of `-` something like this.

```
  +(void)pauseGame:(id)param{
  }
```

If you post the definition of `pauseGame:` it will help more

**EDIT: USE**

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{ 

     UIViewController *controller = self.window.rootViewController;

     if([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
           BPGameController *bpGameController;

            for (id vc in [((UINavigationController*)controller) viewControllers])
             {
                 if ([vc isKindOfClass:[BPGameController class]])
                 {
                     [((BPGameController *) vc) pauseGame];
                     break;
                 }
             }
     }
     else if([controller isKindOfClass:[BPGameController class]]){
             [((BPGameController *) controller) pauseGame];

     }else{
        //Not found
     }
}
```

Comment: I just tried to change it to a class method but then all my timers didnt work

Comment: - (IBAction)pauseGame
{
    
    [greenTimer invalidate];

Answer (score 0):

if resumeGame doesnt take any param it should just be

```
 [BPGameController resumeGame];
```

lose the ":"